# Complex Media Query

Tags: css, mobile, orientation, media-queries

As always, thanks for your help.

I'm trying to write a complex media query and was wondering if someone out there could help.

- I want to use small.css for all devices that have either a width or height less than 640px in either orientation
- I want to use large.css for all devices that have a have a width and height greater than 640px

Here's the part that's got me - I want to break the rules above and use

- large.css if the device is landscape and has a width greater than 639px
- small.css if the device is portrait and has a width less than 640px

Here's what I have right now

```
  "only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:639px)" 
  "only screen and (min-device-height:320px) and (max-device-width:639px)"
  "only screen and (min-device-width:640px)"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

**The device is landscape and has a width greater than 639px**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-device-width: 639px" href="large.css" />
```

**The device is portrait and has a width less than 640px**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:portrait) and (max-device-width: 640px" href="small.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `(min|max)-device-width` won't help as that's for the width of the device and not the pixel width of a viewport/browser window. This issue however, is somewhat diminished on mobiles/tablets, as the browser is nearly always the full width/height of the device.

In addition, using both width/height options may cause some clashes, especially when used with device orientation, so splitting all your queries *on orientation* might help.

These should give you a starting point:

```
 // small.css
    media="only screen and (max-width:639px) and (orientation: portrait)"

 // large.css  
    media="only screen and (min-width:640px) and (orientation: landscape)"
```

Media queries are not an exact science due to mixed support by device/OS manufacturers. If you look around the web, you can find developer-efforts to meet all sorts of devices.

Worth looking at the following to find examples and whats possible and how you can combine queries to better fit a single device or wider range:

- [Mozilla Developer Network (CSS media queries)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries)
- [W3C Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1)